# How do I use XPath to count the number of nodes with a certain attribute

Tags: xpath, count

I can't seem to get an XPath expression to work for my scenario. I want to find all the "Device" nodes that have the type "EndDevice". I'm able to count all the "Device" nodes, and I'm also able to find all "Device" nodes with the "EndDevice" attribute. However, I can't seem to combine them!

```
count(//Device) //works
//Device[@xsi:type='EndDevice'] //works
count(//Device[@xsi:type='EndDevice']) //doesn't work
```

If it matters, I'm using XPathBuilder.

Comment: What do you mean that the second one "worked"?  Did it match some nodes?  Your XPath looks correct so there is something not working either in a section of code you're not showing, or in the tool you're using.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I reproduced it using XPathBuilder 2.0.0.4.
However the XPath expression works and evaluates correctly in an online evaluator I tried (http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm).

EDIT: Also tried with latest version of Altova XMLspy

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<asdf xmlns:xsi="n/a">
    <Device xsi:type='EndDevice'/>
    <Device xsi:type='EndDevice'/>
    <Device xsi:type='EndDevice'/>
    <Device xsi:type='EndDevice'/>
</asdf>
```

xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsi="n/a">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <output>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//Device[@xsi:type = 'EndDevice'])"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsi="n/a">4</output>
```

I think it's XPathBuilder thats doing something wrong.

Comment: Agreed.  It is likely to be a problem with XPathBuilder.  I tested the XML/XSLT in oXygen using Xalan, Saxon 6.5.5, Saxon HE 9.2.0.3 and got the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Using the above xml saved into a test.xml and using the tool http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/

```
declare namespace xsi="n/a"; 
count(doc('test.xml')//Device[@xsi:type = "EndDevice"])
```

Produces the right output.