# counting number of elements from XML using xpath

Tags: xml, matlab, xpath

I've used this excellent forum to teach myself some basic xpath to query an .XML file. I've got a sample of my XML file here, and I'm trying to import the [X,Y] coordinates of 3 objects in the XML file using Matlab:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ROI array</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Comments</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Unnamed</string>
            <key>ROIPoints</key>
            <array>
                <string>{129.24051549947484, 263.66036033996352}</string>
                <string>{114.61421850240453, 278.56760216125258}</string>
                <string>{123.11826208150609, 289.73859978088149}</string>
                            <string>{125.11111111111111, 295.77777777777777}</string>
            </array>
            <key>Slice</key>
            <integer>58</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Comments</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Unnamed</string>
            <key>ROIPoints</key>
            <array>
                <string>{127.09352448499425, 261.31629753478774}</string>
                <string>{112.50917389905675, 277.25509453185805}</string>
                <string>{126.061969309213, 291.36980247863539}</string>
                <string>{141.48499634778722, 292.16234398254164}</string>
                <string>{149.71229126966222, 277.81281090148696}</string>
            </array>
            <key>Slice</key>
            <integer>59</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Comments</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Unnamed</string>
            <key>ROIPoints</key>
            <array>
                <string>{134.32833430087788, 258.21743274101027}</string>
                <string>{117.0812182120107, 266.44891620048293}</string>
                <string>{114.41427180087788, 292.20427203544386}</string>
                <string>{128.80573603427632, 299.11905932792433}</string>
                <string>{147.92307612216695, 299.11905932792433}</string>
                <string>{152.73700281894429, 285.80526996024855}</string>
                <string>{154.32626673495992, 268.51202655204543}</string>
            </array>
            <key>Slice</key>
            <integer>60</integer>
        </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've managed to export all of the coordinates using this Matlab code:

```
expression_2 = xpath.compile('plist/dict/array/dict/array/string');
nodeList_2 = expression_2.evaluate(docNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for i = 1:nodeList_2.getLength
    node = nodeList_2.item(i-1);
    coordinate_node{i} = char(node.getFirstChild.getNodeValue);
end
```

Does anyone know of an xpath query whereby I could count the NUMBER of [X,Y] coordinates in each object? I.e. something that returns 4 coordinates for the first object, 5 coordinates in the second and 7 coordinates in the 3rd?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. However, the problem is that your code extracts all "string" nodes in a flat way, disregarding parent "array" nodes. This way you cannot tell which coordinate belongs to which object.

If you modify your code a little bit so that it would traverse through the "array" and "string" nodes in a hierarchical way, it can work like you want to:

```
%// Extract 'array' nodes
expr_array = xpath.compile('plist/dict/array/dict/array');
nodeList_array = expr_array.evaluate(docNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
C = cell(nodeList_array.getLength, 1);
for k = 1:nodeList_array.getLength

    %// Extract 'string' nodes
    node_array = nodeList_array.item(k - 1);
    expr_string = xpath.compile('string');
    nodeList_string = expr_string.evaluate(node_array, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    coordinates = zeros(nodeList_string.getLength, 2);
    for m = 1:nodeList_string.getLength
        node_string = nodeList_string.item(m - 1);
        s = char(node_string.getFirstChild.getNodeValue); %// Extract string
        coordinates(m, :) = str2num(s(2:end - 1));        %// Convert to numbers
    end
    C{k} = coordinates;
end
```

Now cell array `C` contains all coordinates (by the way, I converted them to numerical values so that they can be stored in a matrix and manipulated easily):

```
C{1} =
  129.2405  263.6604
  114.6142  278.5676
  123.1183  289.7386
  125.1111  295.7778

C{2} =
  127.0935  261.3163
  112.5092  277.2551
  126.0620  291.3698
  141.4850  292.1623
  149.7123  277.8128

C{3} =
  134.3283  258.2174
  117.0812  266.4489
  114.4143  292.2043
  128.8057  299.1191
  147.9231  299.1191
  152.7370  285.8053
  154.3263  268.5120
```

Now, if you want the number of coordinates in each cell (object), simply do this:

```
cellfun(@(c)size(c, 1), C)
```

and you'll get the desired result:

```
ans=
    4
    5
    7
```

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly what I was looking for. And also a much more elegant solution to my methodology, very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your matlab's XPath implementation, but XPath do have aggregation functions and I have used them with Java:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-count

please refer your matlab's manual on this topic first. You can also have a glance how to use it in this similar question.

[How do I use XPath to count the number of nodes with a certain attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389190/how-do-i-use-xpath-to-count-the-number-of-nodes-with-a-certain-attribute)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have previously read the W3 page, and in my example, I can use the count function fine, i.e. 'count(plist/dict/array/dict/array/string)', but this returns the total number of entries (16) rather that the number of entries in each <array> field. So for simple cases (i.e. W3 and Matlab help files), its really useful, but my case here needs extra tweaking

Comment: If I am understanding your question right, you need to first make a XPath query on "array" node, then iterate each "array" node, count the "string" node in it. It can be done using XPath's indexed selection and relative path query.

Comment: Yes, you've understood correctly. I understand I need to iterate the array nodes, although this is the part I'm unsure how to actually carry out in practice. I can carry out a query to return the fact that there are 3 "sets" of coordinates (simply the length of 'plist/dict/array/dict/array'), but I don't know the xpath command for how to iterate through the returned nodes